# Google Api, authentification

Tags: java, c#

i need to connect to google drive trough service account
i found the code in Java but im not able to trasform in c#

Can anyone transform this code in c#:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.services.sqladmin.SQLAdminScopes;

GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("MyProject-1234.json"))
    .createScoped(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN));
```

Comment: Use code snippets for code examples. What have you tried to do?

Comment: j just found this code on tutorial on google but dinnt found in c#

Comment: Don't try to translate Java code, Google supports a set of .NET wrappers around their APIs (which are in a .NET style).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this using the example Google has given for their Drive API and C# libraries here

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

See the section titled "**ServiceAccountCredential**"

Comment: This is what I followed when consuming the GMail API a couple of years ago (all the packages are on NuGet, eg. [`Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.MVC/).

Comment: Totally right, they do seem to have a handle on their documentation these days